# Is there any way to pass the name of the provisioned product to one of the resources in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-service-catalog

When you provision a product from the AWS Service Catalog, it takes the name of the product as a parameter. However, I would like the name of that product to be passed to the main resource of that product (an EC2 instance). Originally I had no names for my EC2 instances, but I found that if you add a name tag to the CloudFormation template it will name the instance that. But I cannot find any way to have the name of the instance be based on the name that was passed in when provisioning the product from the catalog.

Comment: You probably make use of the `ProvisionedProductId` if you are also using CloudFormation to provision the product. Then, you could use the intrinsic `Fn::GetAtt` function in CloudFormation to use the `ProvisionedProductId` as the `Name` tag for the EC2 instance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationprovisionedproduct.html

Comment: So the problem is the product is provisioned through the AWS Console